# Vuejs sum on event change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have following code that sum price of product to existed number when user increase the quantity of product. But the issue with my code is if user decrease the amount price still gets increased.

## Code

`html`

```
<el-input-number style="width: 100%;" ref="amount" v-on:change="amoutChanged($event, row)" v-model="row.amount" :min="1"></el-input-number>
```

`script`

```
data() {
    return {
        subtotal: 0,
    }
},
methods: {
    amoutChanged: function(event, row) {
        console.log('amount row: ', row);
        console.log('amount event: ', event);
        // ISSUE: regardes that user increase or decrease the amount number this price gets increased
        this.subtotal = parseInt(this.subtotal) + parseInt(row.price);
    },
}
```

[image]

#### Console results

```
amount row:  {barcoded: "8995078803078", …}
  amount: (...)
  barcode_id: (...)
  barcoded: "8995078803078"
  price: (...)
  product: (...)

amount event:  2  // this is amount input by user
```

## Question

How to properly increase and decrease price based on user action?

Comment: you bette use `computed` properties to display the price

Comment: where do you display your data? in a `v-for` loop or?

Comment: What is `el-input-number` here? How do we know if `+` or `-` was clicked?

Comment: @Ifaruki in `v-for`  `<tr v-for="(row, index) in serial_numbers" :key="index">`

Comment: @palaѕн not sure but maybe in docs has something that i didn't see https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input-number#inputnumber

Comment: @palaѕн probably can use `currentValue, oldValue` mentioned in docs

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r87b4e3x/) to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн here you go https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/ahLr9vyu/6/

Comment: @mafortis yes, i saw the fiddle and need o rethink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it like this:

I changed `subtotal` to an computed propertie and sum it with `.reduce()` and i added a new property called `singlePrice` so we can multiply with it

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      serial_numbers: [{
        barcode_id: '45634643',
        product: 'dfgs546',
        amount: 1,
        price: 100,
        singlePrice: 100,
      },{
        barcode_id: '23523fd',
        product: 'rgdg46546',
        amount: 1,
        price: 100,
        singlePrice: 100,
      },{
        barcode_id: 'fdghdh',
        product: '345634643',
        amount: 1,
        price: 100,
        singlePrice: 100,
      }],
      total: 0,
      num1: 1
    };
  },
  computed: {
     subtotal(){
    
       return this.serial_numbers.reduce((a,v)=> a + v.price,0)
     }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
     var barcodes = document.createElement('tr');
      this.serial_numbers.push({
        barcode_id: '675476547',
        product: 'hjfgj67',
        amount: 1,
        price: 100,
        singlePrice: 100,
      });
    },
    removeElement: function(index) {
      this.serial_numbers.splice(index, 1);
    },
    amountChanged($event, index){
       let amount = $event;
       this.serial_numbers[index].amount = amount;
       this.serial_numbers[index].price = this.serial_numbers[index].singlePrice * amount;
    }
  }
};
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.4.0/lib/theme-default/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.4.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Serial Number</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Product</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
        <td width="50"></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in serial_numbers" :key="index">
        <td>
          <el-input ref="barcoded" v-model="row.barcode_id"></el-input>
        </td>
        <td>
          <el-input ref="product" v-model="row.product" readonly></el-input>
        </td>
        <td>
          <el-input-number style="width: 100%;" ref="amount" @change="amountChanged($event, index)" v-model="row.amount" :min="1"></el-input-number>
        </td>
        <td>
          <el-input ref="price" v-model="row.price" readonly></el-input>
        </td>
        <td>
          <el-link :underline="false" type="danger" v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer"><i class="fa-2x el-icon-remove"></i></el-link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <el-button type="primary" class="button btn-primary" round @click="addRow"><i class="el-icon-circle-plus"></i> Add row</el-button>
  </div>

  <el-row :gutter="10">
    <el-col :span="8" :offset="16">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th width="100"><strong>Sub total</strong></th>
            <td>
              {{subtotal}}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th width="100"><strong>Total</strong></th>
            <td>
              {{total}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
</div>
```

Comment: `[Vue warn]: The computed property "subtotal" is already defined in data.` Demo code https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/ahLr9vyu/6/

Comment: @mafortis yea, you need to remove it from data

Comment: @mafortis i have updated it, you need to remove the `subtotal` in data

Comment: `Computed property "subtotal" was assigned to but it has no setter.`

Comment: @mafortis check this out

Comment: still get `[Vue warn]: Computed property "subtotal" was assigned to but it has no setter.` also `price` itself is single price why would we need it repeatedly? can't we just multiply with price itself?

Comment: one more thing now my subtotal has extra 0 in front `020000`

Comment: did you open your console F12 and check for errors?

Comment: check for typo at `amoutChanged` i have used `amountChanged`

Comment: yes that i just figured and i get this now `TypeError: Cannot set property 'amount' of undefined`

Comment: @mafortis at what line exactly?

Comment: hmm did you changed row to index here ? `@change="amountChanged($event, index)"`

Comment: @mafortis well then change `row` to `index` like in my example

Comment: ok just did that and it messed all numbers :)) wait i take screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215138/discussion-between-ifaruki-and-mafortis).